# SOQL : Field not found but it exist

Tags: soql, error, orderitem

I am doing a simple query on orders but I get an error :

Query:

```
Select Id,(SELECT Id, OrderId, LineNumber from OrderItems) From Order
```

Error:

```
No such column 'LineNumber' on entity 'OrderItem'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

But the field exist ([Doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_orderitem.htm)) :
[image]

Any Idea?

Comment: It could be an API version issue. That field is available in 48.0 or later as noted in the documentation you linked. Likewise, from the doc `To access Commerce Orders fields, your org must have a Salesforce Order Management license`

Comment: I am executing the query thought rest API so I tried with many different version. I noticed that the field is not existing on workbench but it is existing on object manager.

Comment: It can also be due to permissions when executed in a user mode context. If the user doesn't have at least read permission for the field, you can't query it.

Comment: You are rights the field was not visible, thanks